# I am trying to compress files in python and seem to be struggling

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was trying to get a file so that it saves to a list a sentence in numerical 
form e.g.

this is a sentence and is good = 1,2,3,4,5,2,6

see, is = 2 and is repeated as shown above

this is a section from my code...

```
j = sentence

for position, word in enumerate(sentence):
    if word in word_dictionary:
        word_dictionary.append(position)
```

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
word_dictionary = {} # start with empty dictionary
highest = 0 # and set our counter to 0
sentence = "this is a sentence and is good".split()
compressed = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in word_dictionary:
        highest += 1 # new word, so we need a new number
    # append the word number, and if it's not in the dictionary,
    # set it, too
    compressed.append(word_dictionary.setdefault(word, highest))
```

This correctly sets `compressed` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6]`.